# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la función de JavaScript se realice?

Tags: javascript

El  detalle esta en la función `agregarproducto` que por que llamo de una vez el dato no reconoce el `onChange="Calcular(this);"`

```
function RefrescaProducto() {
            var ip = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
            $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
                i++;
                ip.push({
                    id_pro: $(this).val()
                });
            });
            // Si la lista de Productos no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
            if (i > 0) {
                $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            var ipt = JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
            $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
        }

    function agregarProducto() {

        var sel = $('#pro_id').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
        var text = $('#pro_id').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select
        var envioxd = $('#xxx').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
        var textoxd = $('#xxx').text(); 

        var sptext = text.split();
//<td><input class="form-control" type="text"  id="precunit[]" name="lista[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td>
        var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
        newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="lista[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td class="form-control" type="text"  id="precunit[]" name="lista[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0">'+ envioxd + '</td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="totalitem[]" name="lista[]" readonly /></td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

        $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

        **texto en negrita**RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos

        $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
            var total = document.getElementById("total");
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].value);
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
            if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
            RefrescaProducto();

            Calcular(e.target);
        });
        $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
            RefrescaProducto();

        });
    }


    function Calcular(ele) {
        var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0 ;
        var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
        var nodes = tr.childNodes;

        for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {

            if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'cantidad[]') {
                cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
            }
            if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'precunit[]') {
                precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
            }
            if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'totalitem[]') {
                anterior = nodes[x].firstChild.value;
                totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
            }
        }
        // Resultado final de cada fila ERROR, al editar o eliminar una fila
        var total = document.getElementById("total");
        if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
            total.innerHTML = 0;
            // 
        }
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem -anterior ;    
    }
```

- **Elemento de lista**

Comment: gracias  por colocarlo de mejor forma xD

Comment: Puedes añadir el html?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el HTML con el que estás interactuando en el javascript para poder entender tu código

Comment: gracias ya lo he solucionado